# My viewcontroller is not being deinitialized after show segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created two view controllers, each with a button that does a show segue to the other view controller.

```
var counter = 0
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        counter += 1

        print("init viewc \(counter)")
    }

    deinit {
        counter -= 1
        print("deinit viewc \(counter)")
    }
}
```

It seems like deinit is never called, each time i return to ViewController, the counter is increasing:

```
init viewc 1
init viewc 2
init viewc 3
```

And so on... Am i missing something here? I thought show segue was supposed to release the caller from memory since it is no longer needed. Am i creating new ViewController objects every time I segue now?

Comment: Are you modally segueing between VC's connected in Storyboard?

Comment: No, i selected "show", not "present modally"

Comment: Did you try presenting your VC by instantiating them?

Comment: No I want to make it work by segueing since I have a memory leak in another project. It seems that segueing like this might not work as I expect it to though, since as far as I can see, the view controllers are not being trown away (so that might be the cause of the leak?).

Comment: Try present modally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a "show" segue, you are creating a new view controller instance each time, effectively presenting the top an ever deeper "stack" of view controllers.

If you want to switch back and forward between single instances of your view controllers then you could use a container view controller, such as a `UITabBarController` or use a `UINavigationController` and manipulate the `viewControllers` property

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by segueing to one view controller and then unwinding back to the first one (first view controller stays but is reused and the second one is deleted). There is no navigation controller holding them. Is this an okay solution or could it present other problems? I.e. should one always contain them in a navigation controller when doing this?

Comment: No, an unwind segue is fine. If there is no navigation controller then you are simply presenting the second view controller modally on top of the first, and then discarding the second when you unwind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to let go of a viewcontroller that came prior to one you want to keep, and f you don't intend to do an `unwind segue` and return to a previous `view controller`'s latest state, and you want to deallocate a prior view controller, then you are essentially treating one of the later view controllers as a new `rootViewController`, and until you reassign the root view controller property on the `AppDelegate` that first view controller won't be deallocated due to the `rootViewController` having a strong reference to it.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = VCTwo
```